# How to get the value of corresponding text from select option in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select element with a bunch of options values. For example, data option in the HTML snippet is autogenerated and its value and index are randomly assigned. I would like to get the value of data option from the select element. I can get all the option values from the select element but I cannot get value for the corresponding text. Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<select id="selectId" name"data">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="86">data</option>
        <option value="76">Second</option>
        <option value="68">Third</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: The `.selectedIndex` property of the `<select>` element tells you which `<option>` is currently selected.  You can then use the `.value` of the `<option>`.

Comment: I want to get the option value without selecting it.

Comment: Well then iterate through the `.options` list on the `<select>`. Have you [ready any documentation at all?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)

Comment: I can get all the values. However, my problem is I don't know the index of the option or its value because they are randomly assigned. I only know the text of option. So from the text, I would like to find its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make an arrary for All Options, then simply use a array.find method

```js
const allOPtions   = [...document.querySelectorAll('#selectId option')]
  ,   getOptionVal = oTxt => allOPtions.find(x=>x.textContent===oTxt).value
  ;
  
console.log( 'value of option->"data" =', getOptionVal('data') )
```

```html
<select id="selectId" name"data">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="86">data</option>
  <option value="76">Second</option>
  <option value="68">Third</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectId = document.querySelector('#selectId')
selectId.addEventListener("change", function () {
  const option = this.value;
  console.log(option)
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for my case because I want to get the value without selecting any option.

Comment: Which value do you need? The first one or all of them?

Comment: Let's say Second but the problem is I don't know the index of the option or its value because they are randomly assigned every time. The only thing for the option that doesn't change is its text. So from the text, I would like to find its value.